# Granting access on DMVs in SQL DW

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to have the user accounts(local user accounts created on the database) access to the DMVs(like "sys"."dm_pdw_errors" ...) available in SQL DW by running 
grant VIEW DATABASE STATE to srvc_sales_order_writer

but this is failing with

> Msg 104001, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near 'VIEW'.

Reference on granting permission [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178569.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please provide some more of the lines of code around the `VIEW` statement exactly as it is in your code to give us a chance to see the "incorrect syntax" that the message is referring to.

Comment: GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO srvc_details_writer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a defect, this is currently broken.  The defect has been fixed and the fix will roll-out in the next monthly update.  Currently, to query SQL DW specific DMVs, those with "pdw" in the name, the user will need db_owner privileges.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'myuser';
```

Once fixed, these statements will work.

```
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO myuser;
OR
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE ON DATABASE::mydb TO myuser;
```

Comment: Thanks Sonya. Do you know- when does this next monthly update happens ? Any timeframe that i can share it with my users ? Also, Granting do_owner will grant users some more permissions right ? ( I mean not just on DMV,s, but also to create some objects ? on entire DB)

Comment: This is now fixed.